# Error when trying to import MoPub lib in a Swift App (error: use of undeclared type)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to import the Mopub library to a new Swift project. Following this steps:

1. Create new Swift Project + pod init
2. Add the pod `pod 'mopub-ios-sdk`
3. `pod install`
4. Open the project (file `.xcworkspace`)
5. Create a dummy ObjectiveC file to be prompted to add the Bridging headers
6. In the `MyProject-Bridging-Header.h`file add the line `#import <MoPub/MoPub-Bridging-Header.h>`

At this point the project compiles but if I try to use a class of the framework XCode complains with `error: use of undeclared type MPInterstitialAdController`

Where is the error?

Note: If I create the App Project is ObjectiveC using the import line to `#import <mopub-ios-sdk/MoPub-Bridging-Header.h>` in the step 6 is enough to make the framework accesible from the swift code. But I need my project to be based in Swift.

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve the issue ?

Comment: I am integrating mopub in swift project , while i am running in simulator i am not getting any issue but while i am running in device , its says mopub module not found 

adding header file also import mopub bridging header but it did not accept any of following command

//#import <mopub_ios_sdk/MoPub-Bridging-Header.h>
//#import <MoPub/MoPub-Bridging-Header.h>

i have tried one by one plus in my pod file use framework keyword is mentions.

I also check out : https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-in-import-mopub-statement-in-swift-app/38757/5
but nothing helps me out.
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the bridging headers I was missing the import statement:

```
import MoPub
```

:P